# Python 1e7 and % operator

Tags: javascript, python

I am currently reverse engineering javascript code where I ran across this code

```js
timestamp % 1e7
```

This code in javascript outputs number that looks like this

```js
4822529
```

Same code written in python like this gives back a completely different number.

```py
>>> time.time() % 1e7
9645047.76914692
```

Am I not using these operators correctly?

Comment: im not very good at javascript, can you clear what `timestamp` means?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `time.time` returns the number of seconds since the epoch, something like:

```
1609645359.6018794
```

The 7 numbers before the decimal are `9645359`. There are a total of 10 digits before the decimal.

But in JS, timestamps are often given in the number of *milliseconds* since the epoch:

```js
console.log(Date.now());
```

```
1609645512558
```

or thereabouts. That's 1000 times larger, so the value is significantly different; there are 13 digits before the decimal.

You'll see the pattern if you line up the numbers in the different languages 3 figures apart:

```
   4822529
9645047
```

If you run them at the same time, that `4822` and `5047` will be even closer together.

If you wanted the Python to match the JS output, modulo in Python by `1e4` instead.

If you wanted the JS to match the Python output, modulo in JS by `1e10` instead.

Comment: Is it possible to get timestamp in JS format similarly in python? The values are hugely different. I want to get it as close to Date.now().

Comment: You can use `% 1e4` instead in the Python code if you want a similar output to the JS.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's `Date.now()` returns time in milliseconds, whereas Python's `time.time()` returns time in seconds. If you multiple Python's time by `1000` you'll get similar results.

```js
> Date.now() % 1e7
5615760
```

```py
>>> time.time() * 1000 % 1e7
5637124.4873046875
```

You can also strip off the decimal portion by converting to `int`:

```py
>>> int(time.time() * 1000 % 1e7)
5637124
```